# ubuntu store on mx4 is no longer working

Tags: meizu-mx4

I deleted all subfolders of /home/phablet/.cache, as it is growing very fast and reach the maximum storage capacity of the phone. everything was ok except for the ubuntu store app which is no longer displaying anything and I am now unable to install new apps
any ideas of how to restore this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution myself. I just opened a terminal, and completely remove the ~/.cache folder (`rm -R ~/.cache`), then reboot the phone, and the ubuntu app store is now properly working.
(When I did the cleanup at first stage, I just deleted few folders from .cache and not all of them. This had probably lead to a confusing situation for the app store).